# How to differentiate the first time registered and regular logged in user in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

I am using django allauth for all my `signin, signup and logout` functionality and working fine.

Now i have a functionality that,

1.when a user is registered and logged in for the first time, i need to redirect him to a success page/verification page(`/success/`)

2.When a user who is already registered is logged in, he should be redirected to `/dashboard/`

As of now i am redirected the user(first time registered and already registered) to `/dashboard/` by a setting called `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /dashboard/
```

Also i have observed that there is field/attribute called last_login for user object from which we can use to find the last login for the user, whether it will be helpful ?

**model.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length = 45, null = False, blank = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)
    work_field = models.CharField(max_length = 45, null = False, blank = False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/images/', null = True, blank = True, max_length = 250)
    image.allow_tags = True
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: Do you use AUTH_USER_MODEL (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)?

Comment: Please show your model. What is a parent class for your model?

Comment: Is this for social login, or for login/registration using a form?

Comment: no, it is for login/registration actually, so when a user tried to login, i need to workout the about functionality and based on that need to redirect the user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can check your **last_login** field (if you are sure a user exists).

Try one of the next:

```
profile.user.last_login == profile.user.date_joined: # this may be True if a user logins for a first time
```

OR

```
profile.user.last_login == None:
```

I don't know the exactly value for the field but you can experiment and find the rule for first-time registered users.

Comment: Actually i need to do this in settings.py ? because of i am using django-allauth, i need to give a url to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL based on first registered or regular user right ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Did you mean the users who entered to admin of your site?

Comment: no, the user who tries to register/ login to my front end page

Comment: You can redirect from a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL page.

Comment: actually i am not using any kind of view, just using django-allauth default template url like <form class="login uniForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">

Comment: So how to redirect using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py

Comment: I don't know - how. I'm not sure it's possible. settings.py does not contain structures for that conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view using a  authenticate(), than when you get the user object use the instance method .last_login and it will return either null or true so make a variable with a string to whatever you'll do if it's reverse or etc. Than use login() to login the user and return the variable that was decided by the user object method last_login. You would also have to find a template and define a url on yp ur urlconf. You can find many templates creating a custom form for your view