# Can I check if a user is logged in for the first time after this user is logged in? - Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, django-authentication

I'm trying to catch the first time someone logs in so I can redirect him/her to another page then normally.

I'm working with groups. A admin can make a group with multiple users (with generated usernames and passwords). So it can be that a user is already created before the user logs in (There is no register form for just one user)

This is the code that I want:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user:
        user = request.user
        if user.last_login is None:
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

I've read about checking user.last_login but for this case that doesn't work because it checks this method AFTER the user logs in. Which means that user.last_login is never None.

Can someone help me how can see when a user logs in for the first time?

Comment: Raining ideas, you could create a model that has user as foreign and a boloean field called for example "First_login" that when you create user for the first time creates also a record on that model with that field in false state so you can check, then when the first login occurs, change it to True. Some may say it's unpractical but i guess it's a perspective matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `last_login` value is set via a signal which happens at login, but before your code executes, so you never see `None` as you've discovered.

One way to achieve what you want could be to register your own signal receiver to set a `first_login` attribute somewhere, e.g. in the user's session, before updating the `last_login` value.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login

def update_first_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    if user.last_login is None:
        # First time this user has logged in
        kwargs['request'].session['first_login'] = True
    # Update the last_login value as normal
    update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs)

user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login)
user_logged_in.connect(update_first_login)
```

Then in your view, you'd just need to check the session for the `first_login` attribute.

```py
def index(request):
    if request.user:
        if request.session.get('first_login'):
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

Comment: Using request.session.pop('first_login key', None) will prevent user to be redirect at each login (or delete the key with : del request.session['first_login'])

Comment: This didn't work for me, in my case even before the signal reciever is triggered and update_first_login is executed, the last_login is updated by the django framework reciever. The above code will work some times but is not reliable as the original reciever within the django framework may execute and update last_login. So when update_first_login function executes it dosent not set first_login to True as its already set in the db. An alternative would be to add a field in the user model or related model which keeps track of the login either in a counter or boolean variable.

Comment: Another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126536/how-to-differentiate-the-first-time-registered-and-regular-logged-in-user-in-dja suggests using the condition profile.user.last_login == profile.user.date_joined which is again unreliable as your function will keep executing multiple times on the same day if the user logs in and out multiple times the same day.

Answer (score 0):

It was a big problem to me at once but i found a way to do it easy.
Make a different variable to save the value of the users logged in data, when user is trying to login.

Check my code:

```
if user.last_login is None:
   auth.login(request,user)
   return redirect(alertPassword) 
# when user is login for the first time it will pass a value

else:
   auth.login(request,user)
   return redirect(moveToLogin)

def moveToLogin(request):
   return render(request,"home.html")

def alertPassword(request):
   first_login=True
   return render(request,"home.html",{"first_login":first_login})
#it will pass a value to the template called first login is True

#then go to your template and add this

{% if first_login==True%}
#put any thing you want to be done 
#in my case i wanted to open a new window by using script
<script>

    window.open("popUpWindow")

</script>
{%endif%}
```